# Bypass login filter for 1 time when user chose continue as guest

Tags: jsf, authentication, filter

I have a booking page with URL /booking/Create.jsf. I have a filter for URL pattern /booking/* so the user is asked to login on the page /login/signin.jsf before being taken to Create.jsf. But I have a button "Continue as guest" so that user that is not registered can create a booking on Create.jsf page without log-in. How can I make that happen. Any help will be appreciated. My filter looks like

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    UserLoginController loginController = (UserLoginController) req.getSession().getAttribute("userLoginController");

    if(loginController != null && loginController.isLoggedIn()){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else{
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login/signin.jsf");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The page `create.jsf` is considered in the end as public page. So, in order to enable the filter for other pages concerning "booking", just create a new subfolder named for example "user" inside which you should put others pages of "booking", the new url pattern of the filter will be as a result: `/booking/user/*`. This way, the other stuff of booking remains safe and the page `/booking/create.jsf` will be easily available for the users and guests because it's not covered by the filter.

Comment: Thanks Omar, but what i want is when user uses the URL /booking/create.jsf, he first be taken to login page at least once where he will be allowed to choose the option to "continue as guest". Now the user is directly taken to the create.jsf page without being taken to login-page where he can choose to login if he registered.

Comment: Here's a solution not perfect, but can be useful: Providing you've changed the filter's url pattern through the answer, make a copy of the page `create.jsf`, the url of one copy is: `/booking/create.jsf`, the url of the second one is `/booking/user/create.jsf`. For the first url, provide it as a link only in the button "Continue as guest", and this way it should be ignored by the filter.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that if a user types this url `/your-webapp/booking/create.jsf` in the adress bar, he will be directly redirected to the destination, because he didn't pass by login page. (*While you're still new here, whenever you found a useful answer to your future questions, mark it "useful" by marking it "As accepted" or/and voting it up, in order to help as much as possible future readers/visitors to these questions.)